# web api docker container

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker

I've containerized(docker desktop) a web api core, but know cannot access the localhost SQL Server(**no image**) anymore.

```
"MyDBContext": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I get the error: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Target OS is **Linux**

Will probably get the same issue with emulators running on localhost.

Comment: From a networking perspective each Docker container is its own Linux VM, so `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all refer to the container itself. If SQL Server is running on the Docker host have you tried to use the special host name, `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried `host.docker.internal` instead

Comment: What version (and edition) of SQL Server do you have installed on the Docker host?

Comment: Have you configured your local SQL instance using [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16) to [allow TCP connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver16#SSMSProcedure)?

Comment: I used `host.docker.internal` in connection string and also allowed TCP connections, but this leads to the application stop working, I mean in debug modus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string must be `"MyDBContext": "Server=host.docker.internal;Database=MyDb;User=sa;Password=sa123;"`

**SQL Server and Windows Authentification mode** must be enabled

[image: SQL Server and Windows Authentification mode mus be selected]

And as Dan Guzman mentioned TCP connections must be allowed.